# cat: invalid option -- 'F' error trying to run linux command from python subprocess

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk, subprocess

**Command to run**

```
['ssh', 'tara@ds0', 'sudo', 'cat', '/etc/shadow', '|', 'awk', '-F":"', "'{print $1}'", '|', 'uniq']
    <><><><><>
    Successfuly fetched from  ds0 /etc/shadow

['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/shadow', '|', 'awk', '-F":"', "'{print $1}'", '|', 'uniq']
    <><><><><>

    cat: invalid option -- 'F'
```

As you can see above I have kept the command to run in a list which is than run by python **subprocess** module
The problem here is the first command with **ssh** is working fine but when running the command in **localhost** is **throwing the invalid option -F error**

I have used -F to filter the result to remove password from the result.

**I have tested the code manually running `sudo cat /etc/shadow | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | uniq` and it is running and giving me the expected result**

Why am I getting that error: cat invalid option -- 'F' . Where might have the things gone wrong. Why is the subprocess not able to handle it.

Comment: Have you tried running `ssh tara@ds0 sudo cat /etc/shadow | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | uniq`?

Comment: yes that one is running and giving me the result @Evert

Comment: And does just `['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/shadow']` work with subprocess?

Comment: absolutely  Working ,why is it not working for the localhost case. @Evert

Comment: Did you test `['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/shadow']` on ds0, or on localhost as well?

Comment: yest  it is working in all the cases @Evert

Answer (score 1):

Subprocess will consider as | or -F is the cat prameters. Cat dont have this parameters. If you have list and want to use subprocess use like this.

```
 p = ['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/shadow', '|', 'awk', '-F":"', "'{print $1}'", '|', 'uniq']
output = subprocess.check_output(' '.join(p),shell=True)
print output # you will get expected output
```

OR ....... If you want to give string

```
p = 'sudo cat /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{print $1}' | uniq'
output = subprocess.check_output(' '.join(p),shell=True)
print output # you will get expected output
```

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a pipe operator, interpreted by shell. To have it interpreted, you need to tell subprocess that your command is to be run in a shell - you do it by adding keyword parameter `shell=True`. Without that, you're executing cat command with several parameters, `|` and `-F":"` among them. And `-F` is not a valid option for cat (as the error message says).

Comment: That filter is  for the awk why is it taking for the cat instead. shell=True is not the correct and not advisable for security Reason,If it is so why is it working for other HOST

Comment: In the first example, you are executing ssh. This makes an SSH connection to the remote hosts and runs a command in a shell, by default. All arguments after 'ssh' are passed to the shell on the remote host, not to the shell on localhost. In the second example, however, you really need to tell you want a shell to interpret your command.

Comment: Previously I used to serve the output of cat as the input to filtering that is recommended as the best way from security prospective. Shell=true is not recommended. Turning on shell=True is problematic to my application. So may be serving the output of one as input to other is the best way. Thanks all

Comment: If you really don't want to use shell, do not use pipe. Instead use just `['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/shadow']` and then process the output in Python rather than running it through awk and uniq.

Comment: Yes I have done that too but for the security reason i want to eliminate the password section ahead . That is why I am using the filters. @user204560